# Deploy my React project from Github to Netlify

Tags: github, environment-variables, netlify

Basically I have a .env file in the project, however it will be ignored when I commit by git regarding to .gitignore, which also makes it kind of disappear when Netlify deploys this project from GitHub. Then I have to manually set my environment variables on Netlify.

Are there any other ways to do this, so I don't have manually set the environment variables in Netlify and it will read my .env file?

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question but if you want Netlify to read your `.env` file, then just commit it along with your sourcecode to the repo on GitHub. Otherwise you will have to set it in your `Settings > Build & deploy > Environment > Environment variables` section like you've been doing. There is no other way as far as I understand

Comment: It's how I'm doing it now, and it WORKS so far. However, it'll be sorta annoying if there are too many environment variables to add. By the way, what if I deploy it in Netlify directly, not via Github? Will it ignore .env file as well when it builds the production?

Answer (score 2):

Netlify supports [environment variables](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/environment-variables/), not through `.env` though. You'll need to configure these either through your dashboard or or in the netlify configuration file.

#### File

> In the Netlify configuration file. File-based configuration allows you
>   to set different environment variables for different deploy contexts.
>   Variable values set in the configuration file will override values set
>   in the UI.

#### Dashboard

> In your site dashboard under Settings > Build & deploy > Environment >
>   Environment variables. Variable values set under site settings will
>   override the team-level settings.

Comment: Never knew it can be configured by Netlify file, thanks for the knowledge! It's sad to know it can't read environment variables through .env file though.